# error installing BRugs "C compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: c, r, gcc, compiler-construction

I am trying to install the R library BRugs on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

But I get the following error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘BRugs’ ...
** package ‘BRugs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for prefix by checking for OpenBUGS... /usr/bin/OpenBUGS
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpnNLTG1/R.INSTALL488b7635d4c0/BRugs':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘BRugs’
* removing ‘/home/myuser/lib/R/BRugs’
Warning in install.packages("BRugs") :
  installation of package ‘BRugs’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp2ytOWn/downloaded_packages’
```

Here is a link to [config.log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18092793/config.log). It is difficult to tell what the error is, except that the errors starts with `gcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'`.

How can I get around this error (and install BRugs)?

Comment: 1) Probably in `/tmp/RtmpnNLTG1/R.INSTALL488b7635d4c0/BRugs`. 2) Did you follow the instructions in [Chapter 1: Creating R packages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Creating-R-packages) of *Writing R Extensions*?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich 1) `/tmp/RtmpnNLTG1/` does not exist 2) I am doing so now.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential` in your shell before installing BRugs if you have not done before. Maybe this installs any missing dependency.

Comment: @halex I already have the `build-essential` package

Comment: @David: Paragraph 3 of my reference cites *R Installation and Administration*; be sure to read [Appendix A](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Essential-and-useful-other-programs-under-a-Unix_002dalike) of that manual.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich all I can find is the [configure and cleanup](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Configure-and-cleanup) section, but I can't find the `configure.ac` file that it says I likely need to edit.

Comment: `configure.ac` is in the package tarball: `tar -zxf BRugs_0.8-0.tar.gz && ls -l BRugs/configure.ac`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich thanks, even after making the suggested changes to `configure.ac` and then running build / install, I get the same error.

Comment: Run `./configure` from `BRugs/` and add the relevant section from `configure.log` to your question.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I have updated the question with a [link to the entire config.log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18092793/config.log) since there were a lot of errors and it is not clear to me which are relevant.

Comment: What happens if you change line 2204 in file `configure` from `for ac_option in --version -v -V -qversion; do` to `for ac_option in --version -v; do` and run ./configure?

Comment: @halex this fixes errors related to `gcc -V` and `-qversion` but the next error "cannont find crt1.o` is still there, along with subsequent errors (`incompatable lgcc.a`, `cannont find -lgcc`, ...)

Comment: Did you ever get it installed?  I'm having the same error, Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, R 3.0.2

Comment: @vitale232 no, JAGS does what I need!

Comment: @David Yeah, looks like there are some other good options out there.  Unfortunately I need to force a code from my professor to run that's written in bugs.  Guess I'll be booting up the old 32 bit machines.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: @vitale232 "BUGS" is a language that is used by different software - WinBUGS, OpenBUGS, and JAGS. There are a few syntax differences, but most scripts will work in all three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the package description:

> Versions running on Linux and on 64-bit R under Windows are in "beta"
>   status and less efficient.

And it looks like `configure` is trying to build the package using 32-bit executables (note the `-m32` flags).  It's probably best if you contact the package maintainer(s) and ask them how to build the 32-bit executable under 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. Although this doesn't solve my problem, our discussion in the comments about building from source was a good learning experience for me. I am happy using JAGS, but just wanted to use BRugs to help figure out my core issue of trying to convert the mcmc.list produced by rjags to a coda object produced by rbugs described in my posts on [this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078152/how-can-i-convert-an-mcmc-list-to-a-bugs-object) and [stats.se](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32462/1381), which remain unanswered despite each having had bounties.